# MongoDB Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages

Tags: laravel, mongodb, composer-php

I am trying to install "jenssegers/mongodb": "^3.6" with composer for a laravel 6 project, my command line is looking at (MongoDB shell version v4.2.0), my PHP version is 7.2, I have 7.2 Thread Safe (TS) x86 driver installed and I have the extension enabled in the php.ini file, any help appreciated, thank you.

> Problem 1

```
- mongodb/mongodb 1.5.0 requires ext-mongodb ^1.6 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
- mongodb/mongodb v1.5.x-dev requires ext-mongodb ^1.6 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
- mongodb/mongodb 1.6.x-dev requires ext-mongodb ^1.6 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
- mongodb/mongodb 1.5.0 requires ext-mongodb ^1.6 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
- Installation request for mongodb/mongodb ^1.5.0 -> satisfiable by mongodb/mongodb[1.5.0, 1.6.x-dev, v1.5.x-dev].
```

> To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini
>   files:
>       - C:\WINDOWS\php.ini   You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution and It was php.ini file not saving when editing with notepad++. So opened the ini file with admin permission.